# Integration between infinity and -infinity

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Given that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(ce^{\frac{-\alpha r}{2a}})^2dr = 1$$

express c in terms of a.

I assume this is meant to be done by solving the integral, but how do you evaluate

$$\frac{2ac}{\alpha}e^{\frac{-\alpha r}{2a}}$$

between $-\infty$ and $\infty$? The answer isn't finite, is it? For $\infty$, the $e$ term will tend to zero, but what about the other one? Or is evaluating the integral the wrong approach?

To give the context of this question, it's related to quantum mechanics. The expression to be integrated is the wavefunction. I am supposed to use the 'normalisation condition' to solve the problem, which I presume is the same normalisation condition which states that the integral between infinity and -infinity of the magnitude of the wavefunction is equal to 1.

Comment: What is the variable of integration please specify

Comment: There seems to be a $\mathrm da$ or $\mathrm dr$ or $\mathrm d\alpha$ or $\mathrm de$ missing

Comment: If this is an integral over $r$ or $\alpha$, it does not converge. With $a$, I don't know.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform True!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform There is actually a square missing! I've added it; does that make much of a difference? I don't think the square is where you meant one should be though...

Comment: @Karacoreable Are you shure that's where the square should be? That still doesn't converge.

Comment: @Lovsovs Unless I have the definition of 'magnitude' wrong. I'll edit my post to add some context, I think. One moment.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It doesn't explicitly state that, but it must be the case because $r$ is the magnitude of two vectors $|a-b|$.

Comment: @Karacoreable See my edit, it gives you the answer given the new context you provided. Note that the squaring of the exponential simply removed the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer:**

Given that $r>0$, we can solve the integral, as the limits now become $0$ and $\infty$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}c^2 e^{\frac{-\alpha r}{a}}=-c^2 \frac{a}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dr} e^{\frac{-\alpha r}{a}}=-c^2 \frac{a}{\alpha}\left[0-1 \right]=c^2 \frac{a}{\alpha}$$
so 
$$c^2 \frac{a}{\alpha}=1 \leftrightarrow c=\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{a}}$$ is your normalization constant.

**Previous answer:**

As it is now, then no, your integral does not converge. Assuming that it was meant to be a Gaussian (which I think was the intention), it can be evaluated:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ce^{\frac{-\alpha r^2}{2a}}=c\sqrt{\frac{2r\pi}{\alpha}}$$
which can be shown using [a very cute trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates) of squaring the integral.

In this case $c$ is easily found.

Comment: Oh! Wow, thank you. Sorry about missing out so much information, I will definitely bear that in mind in future!

Comment: @Karacoreable No problem! :)